# How do I reverse an SVG curve built using an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, svg, trigonometry

I'm new to c#/svg and am attempting to convert a relative <90 curve whose points exists in an array: `float arcArray[2,4]` and trying to keep everything in my `ArcPlot` class `using System` only and put the actual svg functions within a separate class.

This will produce the correct curve visually but I need it to go in the opposite direction to append to an existing svg string:

```
float [,] arcPoint = ArcPlot.arcPointsArray(StartAngle, SweepAngle, Radius, -RadiusOffset, Clockwise);
svgOut += " m " + arcPoint[0, 0] + " " + arcPoint[1, 0] + " c " + arcPoint[0, 1] + " " + arcPoint[1, 1] + " " + arcPoint[0, 2] + " " + arcPoint[1, 2] + " " + arcPoint[0, 3] + " " + arcPoint[1, 3];
```

This:

```
float [,] arcPoint = ArcPlot.reverseArcArray(ArcPlot.arcPointsArray(StartAngle, SweepAngle, Radius, -RadiusOffset, Clockwise));
svgOut += " m " + arcPoint[0, 0] + " " + arcPoint[1, 0] + " c " + arcPoint[0, 1] + " " + arcPoint[1, 1] + " " + arcPoint[0, 2] + " " + arcPoint[1, 2] + " " + arcPoint[0, 3] + " " + arcPoint[1, 3];
```

using this function:

```
public static float[,] reverseArcArray(float[,] ArcArray)
{
    float [,] arcArray = ArcArray;
    float [,] swapArray = new float [2,4];
    swapArray[0, 0] = arcArray[0, 3] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 0] = arcArray[1, 3] - arcArray[1, 3];
    swapArray[0, 1] = arcArray[0, 2] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 1] = arcArray[1, 2] - arcArray[1, 3];
    swapArray[0, 2] = arcArray[0, 1] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 2] = arcArray[1, 1] - arcArray[1, 3];
    swapArray[0, 3] = arcArray[0, 0] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 3] = arcArray[1, 0] - arcArray[1, 3];
    return swapArray;
}
```

starts the curve in the right place `(0,0)` and the remaining three control points are close, but are offset by something I'm overlooking.  I'm assuming it's the difference between absolute and relative arcs and I'm missing something simple like a deduction on the actual curve coordinates.

Brute forcing/trial and error is not working for me.

I first attempted this with `ArcPlot.arcPointsArray(StartAngle + SweepAngle, SweepAngle, Radius, -RadiusOffset, !Clockwise)` without luck either, and this would be the preferred method to avoid reversing altogether but, again, I'm obviously missing something.  I would still like to figure out the reverse function, as well, to better my understanding of relative svg.

If it helps, this is the actual function I use to create the arc:

```
public static float[,] arcPointsArray(double StartAngle, double SweepAngle, double Radius, double RadiusOffset = 0d,
                                      bool Clockwise = false, float XCenter = 0f, float YCenter = 0f)
{
    double radius = Radius, startAngle = StartAngle, sweepAngle = SweepAngle, radiusOffset = RadiusOffset;
    bool arcClockwise = Clockwise;
    float xCenter = XCenter, yCenter = YCenter;

    double startRadiusAngle = arcClockwise ? startAngle - (pi / 2) : startAngle + (pi / 2);
    startRadiusAngle -= Convert.ToInt32(startRadiusAngle / (pi * 2)) * (pi * 2); // mathematical overcircle check
    sweepAngle -= Convert.ToInt32(sweepAngle / (pi * 2)) * (pi * 2);

    double toCenterAngle = arcClockwise ? startAngle + (pi / 2) : startAngle - (pi / 2);
    if (toCenterAngle > (pi * 2)) toCenterAngle -= pi * 2; // functional overcircle check
    if (toCenterAngle < 0) toCenterAngle += pi * 2;
    if (XCenter == 0f) xCenter = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Cos(toCenterAngle) * radius);
    if (YCenter == 0f) yCenter = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sin(toCenterAngle) * radius);

    radius += radiusOffset;

    float[,] arcArray = new float[2, 4];
    arcArray[0, 0] = Convert.ToSingle(xCenter + (Math.Cos(startRadiusAngle) * radius)); // relocate start point
    arcArray[1, 0] = Convert.ToSingle(yCenter + (Math.Sin(startRadiusAngle) * radius));

    double circleFraction = pi * 2 / sweepAngle;
    double bezierLength = radius * 4 / 3 * Math.Tan(pi / (2 * circleFraction));

    arcArray[0, 1] = Convert.ToSingle(arcArray[0, 0] + (Math.Cos(startAngle) * bezierLength)) - arcArray[0, 0];
    arcArray[1, 1] = Convert.ToSingle(arcArray[1, 0] + (Math.Sin(startAngle) * bezierLength)) - arcArray[1, 0];
            
    double endRadiusAngle = arcClockwise ? startRadiusAngle + sweepAngle : startRadiusAngle - sweepAngle;
    if (endRadiusAngle > (pi * 2)) endRadiusAngle -= pi * 2;
    if (endRadiusAngle < 0) endRadiusAngle += pi * 2;

    arcArray[0, 3] = Convert.ToSingle(xCenter + (Math.Cos(endRadiusAngle) * radius)) - arcArray[0, 0];
    arcArray[1, 3] = Convert.ToSingle(yCenter + (Math.Sin(endRadiusAngle) * radius)) - arcArray[1, 0];

    double endAngle = arcClockwise ? endRadiusAngle - (pi / 2) : endRadiusAngle + (pi / 2);
    if (endAngle > (pi * 2d)) endAngle -= pi * 2;
    if (endAngle < 0d) endAngle += pi * 2;
    arcArray[0, 2] = Convert.ToSingle(arcArray[0, 3] + (Math.Cos(endAngle) * bezierLength));
    arcArray[1, 2] = Convert.ToSingle(arcArray[1, 3] + (Math.Sin(endAngle) * bezierLength));

    return arcArray;
}
```

I've seen similar questions in python and javascript but don't understand the syntax or structure enough to translate.

I'm assuming the answer is simply a transposition, incorrect assumption or math error but, if not, pseudocode would be preferred so that I can get the concept rather than cut/paste a solution.

The following gif shows a rotation issue I'm having because the inside relative arc is not being translated properly.  I will deal with that separately as a previous attempt (which doesn't exist anymore since I didn't start using git until after) at rendering everything with absolute positioning doesn't present this issue.  The actual issue I'm having is that the inside arc can be properly rendered but only in the wrong direction.  When reversing it using either the reversing method shown above or using `arcPointsArray` to draw it backwards, those sections need to be identified and concatenated separately rather than using a loop since they require slightly different methods. The idea is to eventually wrap the green line in a red line at a uniform distance, regardless of the starting angle, direction and scale.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkc1x.jpg

Comment: I've reverted your edit. Links to off-site code are not accepted on Stack Overflow because they tend to go stale and thus invalidate questions containing them.

Comment: A better way to enhance your question would be to post images of what the code is doing versus what you expect/require it to do.

Comment: There is other code present that, when the app is running, obfuscates the actual issue I'm having and illustrates a different animation issue that is more easily solvable through translating the arc that I'm trying to produce.  An image, whether still or gif, doesn't present the issue, but I will add a gif if it helps visualize the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just modify your call to `arcPointsArray()`?  Does something like this work?

```
float [,] arcPoint = ArcPlot.arcPointsArray(StartAngle + SweepAngle,
                                            -SweepAngle,
                                            Radius,
                                            -RadiusOffset,
                                            !Clockwise);
```

Comment: That does produce the correct arc but it's inverted on the y-axis.  I can make this work by changing how it concatenates into a string but I do wish I understood why I can't make it work within the function.
`svgOut += " m " + arcPoint[0, 0] + " " + arcPoint[1, 0] + " c " + arcPoint[0, 1] + " " + -arcPoint[1, 1] + " " + arcPoint[0, 2] + " " + -arcPoint[1, 2] + " " + arcPoint[0, 3] + " " + -arcPoint[1, 3];`

Comment: I haven't anyalysed it, but there might be an issue with the function. For instance it might not handle negative sweepAngles or something.  Try putting `Clockwise` back how it was, for example.

Comment: Thank you.  That was most of the solution.  I needed to subtract the SweepAngle instead of add it. This is what worked: `float [,] arcPoint = ArcPlot.arcPointsArray(StartAngle - SweepAngle, -SweepAngle, Radius, -RadiusOffset, Clockwise);` Now back to pencil and paper to figure out why that worked.  It seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I eventually used for reversing the relative cubic svg curve:

```
public static float[,] reverseArcArray(float[,] ArcArray)
{
    float [,] arcArray = ArcArray;
    float [,] swapArray = new float [2,4];
    swapArray[0, 0] = 0f;
    swapArray[1, 0] = 0f;
    swapArray[0, 1] = arcArray[0, 2] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 1] = arcArray[1, 2] - arcArray[1, 3];
    swapArray[0, 2] = arcArray[0, 1] - arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 2] = arcArray[1, 1] - arcArray[1, 3];
    swapArray[0, 3] = -arcArray[0, 3];
    swapArray[1, 3] = -arcArray[1, 3];
    return swapArray;
}
```

My issue was a misunderstanding of the relationship between the first and last coordinates.   The function, as described in the question, would do the job correctly. It would both reverse a relative curve and convert an absolute to relative while reversing.

Since I'm only dealing with relative curves, I can discard the first coordinates since they will always be 0,0 and this can be overwritten with a starting location, as needed.

The solution reached in Paul's answer reveals this to be an **xy problem**.  Re-evaluating how I use the arcPointsArray method eliminates the need for the reverseArcArray method.

I've left this answer so that anyone actually searching for the y problem doesn't get stuck with just the x solution.